# Coefficient of Restitution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the "coefficient of restitution" ( cor ) and the "initial height in meters" ( h ) in two variables. I'm trying to find the "Meters traveled" ( th ) which are cor * h + cor * h + .... the same multiplication until the number of meters is less than 0.10 Meters. What I have done follows :

```
cor = float(input("Enter coefficient of restitution : "))
h = float(input("Enter initial height in meters : "))
nob = 0
th = h
while (h >= 0.10):
    nob += 1
    h *= cor    
    th += h   
print("Meters traveled : {0:.2f}".format(th))
print("Number of bounces : ", nob)
```

For cor = 0.7 and h = 8, I found the result 26.49 meters while my book says 44.82 meters. I do, however, have the correct number of bounces ( 13 ).

Why does my code produce the wrong answer?

Comment: @JohnColeman I disagree. OP has a programming issue where a code set is not resulting in the answer in the book.

Comment: @dfundako OP didn't ask about help with their programming, they were asking if a certain physics calculation was correct. Perhaps they could have phrased their question differently.

Comment: This isn't a question(At least from what I understand and if it is, its very hard to understand.) Besides as @JohnColeman said, this is a physics question. If the question is "Who is correct, Me or the book" The question belongs in the physics, remove this one, and post it there, and make it easier to understand, this is meant to ask questions about your code, not who is right or wrong.

Comment: @dfundako That isn't the question at all. He asked who was right or wrong. He didn't mention at all if there was 1) Anything wrong with his code  2) An Error he was facing (Ex syntax errors etc) This could very well just be an error caused by user error.

Comment: @NaruS Understood and that makes sense.

Comment: @dfundako I edited the question so as to make it on-topic and allow me to upvote your excellent answer. I am retracting my close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears like you are not taking into account the ball travels both down and up when you assign `th`.  The ball drops 8m, then the cor means the ball will come up 5.6m and also drop 5.6m. Change your th += h*2 and that gets closer to your book's answer.

```
cor = float(input("Enter coefficient of restitution : "))
h = float(input("Enter initial height in meters : "))
nob = 0
th = h
while (h >= 0.10):
    nob += 1
    h *= cor    
    th += h*2   
print("Meters traveled : {0:.2f}".format(th))
print("Number of bounces : ", nob)
```

Comment: Upvoting due to this fixing the users need for a more accurate response

Comment: Thank you all, I have changed ...`format(th)` to `format(th - h * 2)` because the exercise asks for the Meters traveled before the ball elevates less than 0.10 Meters from the floor, now I see 44.82 Meters traveled.

Comment: I have click to upvote the answer, however, I'm a new member so, my vote has recorded but not changed the score.

Comment: @i_pap Even if you can't update, you can still accept. There should be a checkmark next to the answer for that purpose.

Comment: @John Coleman I tried to add 2-3 words in dfundako's (excellent) answer just in case to be 100% correct, as my Python manual. But my edit rejected. If someone will search for a similar issue, I believe what I'm trying to do to this answer will be an excellent starting point, so the edit should be reconsidered. Just saying. Thanks.